# How to read download file from path in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode5

I have tried to download and read a file (pdf/epub).
I have achieved download and save the file in below path.

Download path is - file path

```
/Users/apple/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/B5C69537-DBAA-45DA-BDF3-84D0F038378D/Documents/3471.epub
```

But I unable to read from the same path. I am using the below coding for reading the file path.

```
NSString *testpath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3471" ofType:@"epub"];
```

Comment: Please post more code i.e. how are you reading file from this path

Comment: Please refer following [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794747/xcode-6-ios-8-simulator-data-and-bundle-folder-script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSBundle mainBundle` is for the files added to the project folder.

If you need to find any downloaded files saved to documents folder means, try

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *testpath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
```

Comment: Dear Nazik, I used your code and am able to get the path of the file in an NSString variable but I am not able to read the file please find the code below. 
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *testpath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"3471.epub"];
    NSLog(@"the testpath %@",testpath);
    
 if( [za UnzipOpenFile:testpath]){
}

Comment: When you NSLog testpath what are you getting?

Comment: @Saravanan, When you NSLog testpath what are you getting?